Auto formato Visual Studio Code
Tengo en mi ordenador de sobremesa VSC instalado y cuando presiono alt+shift+f da formato a mi código en Java pero en mi portátil no consigo que me haga la misma función. Pensé que seria por tener extensiones diferentes entonces exporté la configuración de usuario al portátil y tampoco, también inicié sesión con Github para tener sincronizada la configuración y tampoco.
Alguien sabe que mas puedo revisar para conseguir que también mi portátil de formato al código?
Gracias.

Valida que la extensión que utilizas si este habilitada

Revisa las siguientes cosas
Usa comando de teclado
ctrl + ,

esto abre settings, ahí en el buscador escribe default formatter y ve si está habilitado para Java, si no esta Java en la lista tienes que instalar una extensión, recomiendo "Language Support for Java by Red Hat"
si esto no funciona anda a
File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts

ahí en el buscador buscar por "format document" ves la combinación de teclas para aplicar el formato de documento, aquí se puede editar a la que tu quieras
a veces otras extensiones interfieren en el formato, aquí ya es prueba y error, deshabilita todas y vas agregando una a una para ver cual es la que provoca el conflicto

Sospecho que también provocaba el problema estar sobre un repositorio en remoto y no en local. He visto que algunas extensiones no funcionan en repositorios virtuales.
